# Hyperbola plotting near real boundary

Tags: plotting

Plotted region above x-axis is jagged due to presence of Sqrt for y coordinate entailing delay in determining onset of real values. There is some improvement with higher number of points chosen,but gets slower.Is there a work around?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
x[ph_, m_] := Sin[ph]/m;
y[ph_, m_] := Sqrt[m^2 - Cos[ph]^2];
ParametricPlot[{x[ph, m], y[ph, m]}, {ph, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {m, 0.5, 2.5},
               PlotStyle -> Yellow, PlotPoints -> {50, 50}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The jagged effect is caused by small imaginary parts popping in near the axis. Try for example `y[10^-4, 10^-4]`. Then, once the cause is known ...

```
x[ph_, m_] = Sin[ph]/m;
y[ph_, m_] = Sqrt[m^2 - Cos[ph]^2];

ParametricPlot[
 Re@{x[ph, m], y[ph, m]}, {ph, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {m, 0.5, 2.5}, 
 PlotStyle -> Yellow, PlotPoints -> {50, 50}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You didn't change too much, did you? Very nice !

Comment: @eldo "a minimalist approach" :)

Comment: @belisarius .. but with maximalist effect!. Thanks.

Comment: +1, pardon my dullness but could you explain how this works? When I plot e.g. `ParametricPlot[{x, Sqrt[Cos[x]]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}]` it seems like `ParametricPlot` is already ignoring any imaginary component?

Comment: @Pickett Compare `x = 10^-4; N@Im@{Sqrt[Cos[x]], Sqrt[x^2 - Cos[x]^2]}`

Comment: Yes, I think my problem was more that why would an imaginary component change anything? If you plot the real component and the imaginary component of fx and fy then you have a four-dimensional object. So I was kind of assuming that it ignored any real component, which was also the case in my example plot. Based on that plot I would expect `ParametricPlot` so simply drop those points and not plot anything there at all so the line would be discontinuous. This was not how I thought about my question at first, perhaps now it is unanswerable/out of scope for this answer.

Comment: @Pickett Not sure if I'm understanding your concern, but ParametricPlot doesn't ignore imaginary components, it considers them "out of region": `ParametricPlot[{x, If[y > x, y, y + 10^-13 I]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]`

Comment: That's a good example that definitely fixed my misunderstanding. Thank you for your help.